# How could we mock methods which are having many database operation inside it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I want to write a unit-test in c# to test those method which are having some database operation (2-3 DB operations) and also some other logics written inside it.

```
private static APIResponse SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, string info)
    {
        APIResponse responseObj = new APIResponse();

        WebResponse response = null;
        // save the log into database.
        Log.Request(request.Method + " to " + request.RequestUri.ToString() + ": " + info);

        try
        {
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;

            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
            {
                responseObj.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
                responseObj.Headers = resp.Headers;

                eTAG = responseObj.Headers["eTag"];

                // save the log into the database.
                Log.Response("<empty>");

                return responseObj;
            }

            // save the log into the database.
            Log.Warning(e.Message);
            response = e.Response;
        }

        if (response == null)
        {
        Log.Response("<null>");
            return null;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

        HttpStatusCode status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();

        if (textResponse != null)
        {
            textResponse = textResponse.Trim();
        }
        // save the log into the database.
        Log.Response(textResponse.Length == 0 ? "<empty>" : textResponse);

        if (textResponse.Length == 0)
            return null;

        responseObj.Headers = response.Headers;
        responseObj.Message = textResponse;
        responseObj.StatusCode = status;

        eTAG = responseObj.Headers["eTag"];

        return responseObj;
}
```

As you can see in snippet , we are saving the logs into the database in between the code various times. How can we mock/stop these logs to be save.

```
public static void Request(string text)
    {
        -- code to save the code in db.
    }

 public static void Response(string text)
    {
        -- code to save the code in db.
    }
```

How could we achieve ? Any guesses anybody ?

Comment: Can you add the code of the method you want to unit test please.

Comment: Generally you want to extract the class that does the database calls as a dependency and inject it via the constructor. That way you can instantiate a test version / a mock of the class and pass it into the class you want to test

Comment: That's a *very* broad question. You can mock the data layer itself and return dummy data, or you can mock the IQueryable (if you use any) and use eg a Dictionary instead of an actual table. You can mock the EF context, if you use EF. You can use a SQLite in-memory DB instead of an actual one. EF Core even has an in-memory DB just for testing

Comment: Post your code if you want specific answers. You didn't even mention *what* data-access technology is used

Comment: Hi Panagiotis.., thanks i have pasted a sample code which somewhat explains the scenario where i want to mock or stop the inserting data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

So using Moq, you're test and class you want to test could look something like this.

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    IDataAccessService _dataAccessService;
    public ClassTotest(IDataAccessService dataAccessService)
    {
        _dataAccessService = dataAccessService;
    }
    public int SomeMethodWeWantToTest()
    {
        // Do Something.
    }   
}
```

Here we use dependency injection to inject the DAL. That way at test time we can pass in a mock.

```
public class ConcreteDataAccessService : IDataAccessService
{
    public List<int> GetSomeNumbersFromTheDatabase()
    {
        // Call db.
        // Get some numbers.
        // Return a list of them.
    }
}

public IDataAccessService
{
    List<int> GetSomeNumbersFromTheDatabase();
}
```

Here we show an interface which represents our DAL. We have a concrete implementation which implements the interface `IDataAccessService` This concrete implementation is what we could call at non test runtime.

```
[TestClass]
public class ClassToTestTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeMethodWeWantToTest_ShouldAddUpAllNumbersFromDatabaseCorrectly()
    {
            Mock<IDataAccessService> dataAccessServiceMock = new Mock<IDataAccessService>();
            dataAccessService.Setup(x=>x.GetSomeNumbersFromTheDatabase()).Returns(new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5});
            ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(dataAccessService.Object());
            int expected = 15;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, classToTest.SomeMethodWeWantToTest());
    }   
}
```

The test class uses Moq, a mocking framework, to mock the DataAccessService and sets up what we want to return when we call the method `GetSomeNumbersFromTheDatabase`.

We then instantiate the class we want to test and pass in the mocked DataAccessService to the class constructor.

This way we can test the functionality of `ClassToTest.SomeMethodWeWantToTest()` without ever hitting an actual database.

Note this code wasn't compiled or checked. It's a rough outline of how to do, very basic, DI and testing. BUt you didn't provide any code in your question...

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I am refactoring the existing code and for that i have written some test for it. but flaw is that there was no data access layer inside the solution so bit hard to achieve.. any help in the case would be appreciated.

Comment: I would create a wrapper around the Log class and put an interface on it, with just the 2 methods you've supplied. Then pass that into the constructor for the class you've shown the method for. Then call the methods on the interface. Now at test time you can mock the Interface.

Comment: Yeah, true but my goal is not only mock Log.Response or Log.Request but also as a whole method "SubmitRequest" which contains these Log saving methods.